# Crontab not running actiona command

Tags: cron

I have a actiona program that I want to run for every hour in my Ubuntu laptop.

```
actiona -s -E -C -Q -e -x '/home/myusername/actionatest.ascr'
```

I test it in terminal and it works.

But when I try to put it in cron, like this:

```
* * * * * actiona -s -E -C -Q -e -x '/home/myusername/actionatest.ascr'
```

it didn't run.

I've made the script and the script is running when I execute it from the terminal. But when I put it in cron, the script didn't run at all

I've tried the debug code, and this is what was displayed when I ran the script from the terminal

`+ source /home/myusername/.bashrc
++ case $- in
++ return
+ actiona -s -E -C -Q -e -x /home/myusername/actiona/actionatest.ascr`

This is the output of the /tmp/log

`QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.`

I have a feeling that this error is caused by some simple step that I should've done, but failed to do.

Comment: At least actiona needs a directory in front of it. and `* * * * *`  is bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wise way is to create script in your home directory like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/myusername/.bashrc
actiona -s -E -C -Q -e -x '/home/myusername/actionatest.ascr'
```

make it executable

```
chmod 755 /home/myusername/script
```

and add it in cron

```
* * * * * /home/myusername/script
```

But be aware that you run this program every minute so its good to adjust the execution schedule.

To debug your script you can modify it on this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
source /home/myusername/.bashrc >>/tmp/log
actiona -s -E -C -Q -e -x '/home/myusername/actionatest.ascr' >>/tmp/log
```

and check file `/tmp/log` to get more information

Comment: I'm new to ubuntu, so I have to search on how to make a script. After creating the script and tried to run it, I got an error that file is not readable or you don't have enough right. Any idea?

Also, when I tried to enter it in cron, still nothing happened. I read that there is a command to start cron, I tried it, and still the script is not running

Of course, I can still run the actiona program by adding a pause for an hour, but still that is not the optimal way, since the Actiona is still running while waiting

Comment: @RudyPrawira, check my edited answer. And do not forget to exec `chmod` command

Comment: I've tried your edited answer, and I can run it in terminal. So thank you. The problem is that cron still won't run it, I tried some sample code (the one that display the date and time every minute) to test if my cron work, and it works. It confuses me that I can run the script from the terminal directly but not from cron. Can you help? Thanks

Comment: @RudyPrawira, add in your script line `set -x` and redirect the output to the file. Check my edited answer

Comment: Please check my edited question, I've added the result of the terminal when I ran the script, but the /tmp/log seems to be empty. I assume that the output should be written on the file when I run the script, or is there something else I should do to send the output to the /tmp/log file?

Comment: @RudyPrawira, try to run the program on this way `nohup actiona -s -E -C -Q -e -x '/home/myusername/actionatest.ascr' >/tmp/log 2>&1 ` and check again the log. Maybe this program need a terminal attached

Comment: This is what I got in the /tmp/log
`QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.`

Comment: @RudyPrawira, your application ask to connect to graphical server. And I am not sure it can run in cron because of this

Comment: Okay, it seems that i just have to let the actiona prgram to keep running. Thank you for the help.